# Install OpenSSL into Red Hat image lacking yum

Tags: docker, oci

I have a container (running image `quay.io/keycloak/keycloak:21.1.1`) where `cat /etc/os-release` reports the following (excerpt):

```
NAME="Red Hat Enterprise Linux"
VERSION="9.1 (Plow)"
CPE_NAME="cpe:/o:redhat:enterprise_linux:9::baseos"
```

`openssl` is not installed, neither is `yum`. (`yum install openssl` fails with "command not found".) So how can I install OpenSSL into such an image (perhaps it is a [UBI micro-image](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_enterprise_linux/8/html-single/building_running_and_managing_containers/index#con_understanding-the-ubi-micro-images_assembly_types-of-container-images))?

Answer (score 0):

The Keycloak image `quay.io/keycloak/keycloak:21.1.1` is currently [based on](https://github.com/keycloak/keycloak/blob/main/quarkus/container/Dockerfile) the Red Hat Universal Base Image `ubi9-micro`, which lacks any package manager (`dnf`, `rpm`, `yum`) in order to minimize size.

I came across a couple of tricks for installing packages regardless, e.g. [one](https://www.redhat.com/en/blog/introduction-ubi-micro) involving `buildah mount` and [another one](https://github.com/fatherlinux/ubi-micro/blob/master/ubi8-micro-openssl) involving multi-stage build plus `yum install --installroot /mnt/rootfs`. The second now serves well in my scenario.